# Using SharedSingleton to call method

Tags: ios

I have a UIviewController. I would to like to add as subview a UIView, but since the UIView doesn't have a viewdidload method, I need to manually call a method. I am doing this using shared singleton in this way:

In the view.m i have:

```
+ (TableLoadGroupMembersViewController *)sharedManager
{
static TableLoadGroupMembersViewController *shaderManager = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    shaderManager = [[TableLoadGroupMembersViewController alloc] init];
});
return shaderManager;
}

- (void)LoadTheView
{
TableViewGroupMembers = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
TableViewGroupMembers.dataSource = self;
TableViewGroupMembers.delegate = self;
[TableViewGroupMembers addSubview:TableViewGroupMembers];
}
```

in the view.h I have

```
+ (TableLoadGroupMembersViewController *) sharedManager;
- (void)LoadTheView;
```

and in the viewcontroller.m I have:

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 300, 100);
TableLoadGroupMembersViewController *view = [[TableLoadGroupMembersViewController alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[self.view addSubview:view];

TableLoadGroupMembersViewController* sharedSingleton = [TableLoadGroupMembersViewController sharedManager];
[sharedSingleton LoadTheView];
```

but the app crashes. Why?

EDIT:

The error is: 0x281db5d:  pushl  %esi ... Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: Given how many questions you ask here, you should know by now that if you post a question about a crash or an error, you need to post details about the error message and/or stack trace.

Comment: Yes your right but the error is not in the code, rather a thread, so I just thought it wouldn't be important

Comment: @Alessandro The error is in the code. Threads don't crash unless the code is wrong. Look at the output in the debugger console or crash log, or at least tell us what line is being executed when the crash happens.

Comment: please see the edit with the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but the app crashes. Why?

So, here you're creating a new instance of your view controller:

```
TableLoadGroupMembersViewController *view = [[TableLoadGroupMembersViewController alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```

**This will crash.** Views have `-initWithFrame` methods, but your view controller probably doesn't.

Next, you're adding that view controller as a subview of `self.view`:

```
[self.view addSubview:view];
```

But a view controller is not a view, *even if if you name the variable `view`*, so you can't add it as a subview. **If the first line didn't crash, this one will.**

It looks like you're confusing your view controller class with a UIView subclass. Take a deep breath, read through the code while pretending that someone else wrote it, and try to figure out what's supposed to be happening here.

(It'd be a big help in the future, however, if you took the time to step through your code in the debugger and identify the specific line that's crashing.)

I'm not convinced (at all) that you need a singleton here for any reason, but the crash is almost certainly a matter of sending messages that the receiver doesn't implement, and it comes down to this confusing between view and view controller.

Comment: thanks for your answers. I use a singleton to call a method in my UIview subclass

Comment: Your view controller doesn't need a singleton to call a method in the view because it already has a pointer to the view. Views don't usually need to call methods in the view controller, but when they do delegation is a better pattern than singleton.

Comment: "Your view controller doesn't need a singleton to call a method in the view because it already has a pointer to the view" so what is the other way to run a method in the UIview? (as there is no viewdidload)

Comment: Ah, now I get it, using - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}